# How to Transfer contact from Lumia 820 (Windows 8.1 \ Denim) to CSV file or to Android Phone - Huawei P9 (Android 6.0)

Tags: contacts, bluetooth, windows, data-transfer

How to Transfer contact from Lumia 820 (Windows 8.1 \ Denim) to CSV file or to Android Phone - Huawei P9 (Android 6.0)

Kindly needs assistances, syncing the outlook accounts along with Google account didn't successfully transfer all the 1980+ contacts.